# Install email_validator using pip

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, email-validation

I have email_validator installed but I am getting an error message saying it is not installed.
Does it have to be installed in my project folder? Or can it be in the main site-packages folder? When I run my program I get this error message:

```
Exception: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support
```

I can see that I have it installed in the main site-packages python3 folder, but when I run

```
pip install email_validator
```

from within my project folder site-packages folder the terminal prints this:

```
site-packages % pip install email_validator
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: email_validator in /Users/STL34/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0.0 in /Users/STL34/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from email_validator) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython>=1.15.0 in /Users/STL34/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from email_validator) (1.16.0)
```

And doesn't install it in my project folder.

Here is the code:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                     validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I used pip with a -t flag to install email_validator in my project folder site packages folder. Without the -t flag pip installs email_validator in the Python3 site-packages folder and that doesn't work.

Comment: You are saving up issues for yourself in future ....   use virtual env so you will not fall into unresolvable package dependencies as the number of projects you have increase and where deployment environment is different to your development machine

Comment: My apologies. The site packages folder I'm referring to is in the venv folder. Here is the path: /projects/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/email_validator.

Comment: ok - you can do with pycharm if you have set your env correctly.  On command line need to initialise venv first with `source venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Inside your virtual environment, just do ```pip install wtforms[email]```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to manage packages so there are no conflicts between projects and site packages are [Virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

**email_validator example**

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-venv python3-pip
mkdir email
cd email
deactivate 2> /dev/null
pip3 show virtualenv
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
   pip3 install --upgrade pip
   pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
   pip3 install virtualenv
fi

# now lets build venv
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install email_validator
echo "import email_validator" > email.py
echo "print(email_validator.validate_email('hello@gmail.com'))" >> email.py
python3 email.py
```

**output**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1).
python3-venv is already the newest version (3.8.2-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
Name: virtualenv
Version: 20.0.25
Summary: Virtual Python Environment builder
Home-page: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/
Author: Bernat Gabor
Author-email: gaborjbernat@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/mcs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: distlib, appdirs, six, filelock
Required-by: 
Collecting email_validator
  Using cached email_validator-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0.0
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting dnspython>=1.15.0
  Using cached dnspython-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (188 kB)
Installing collected packages: idna, dnspython, email-validator
Successfully installed dnspython-1.16.0 email-validator-1.1.1 idna-2.10
<ValidatedEmail hello@gmail.com>
```

Comment: My project is already built in Pycharm. I ran part of you code: `pip3 install email_validator echo "import email_validator" > email.py echo "print(email_validator.validate_email('hello@gmail.com'))" >> email.py python3 email.py` in the venv folder and it worked. But when I run the program from Pycharm, I still get the error message – STL34

Comment: ok - I use PyCharm as well.   Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter : set this to your venv instead of default python installation.  I recommend that you have a requirements.txt and install all your project libraries into your project venv.  Makes deployment far simpler from IDE to runtime env (including cloud)

Comment: Project Interpreter is  set to ~/foldername/venv/bin/python. I'm still getting the error message. I tried copying the email_validator file directly to project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages from the /Users/STL34/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages path. And still get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by it doesn't appear in my project. Could you post the output from doing

```
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
```

in our python file
If you are using `pyenv` then install that module from `pyenv` also.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue with [WTForms](https://pypi.org/project/WTForms/) v3.0.1 package you need to run:

```
pip install wtforms[email]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, `pip install email-validator`.

Sourced from: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/install/